# Material UI styling error. Text and Bottom navigation have bugs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to create a simple website with bottom tabs and a drawer. My First issue is when a bottom tab is selected, it doesn't change its color. After using console.log, I noticed that the value of the tab (i.e. 0, 1, etc...) is being logged meaning it that the tab click is being registered - it is just not changing the style.
Second, the text that I put in in the main screen doesn't change color according to the theme. If you look at the code, I even hardcoded the text object in the palette of my theme but it still doesn't change color. I tried wrapping my  JSX with the  JSX - this made the text change fine but now the paper is styled weird (it isn't taking up the whole main screen and I want to change its background)

Please suggest how I can fix these issues as I am new to React and Material UI.

CodeSandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-demo-bghgp?file=/demo.js

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the `value` prop to the `BottomNavigation` component, like this:

```
<BottomNavigation
   className={className}
   showLabels
   onChange={(event, newValue) => {
     console.log(newValue);
     onChange(newValue);
   }}
   value={value} // <----  You are missing this
>
```

For the Typography problem, you can add a color prop to the component, which points to the theme variable which you want to use for font coloring, like this:

```
<Typography paragraph color="textPrimary">
  Hello
</Typography>
```

For more information: https://material-ui.com/api/typography/